# Where do Javascript UWP apps store IndexedDb?

Tags: javascript, uwp, winjs

I make Windows Store apps with HTML + Javascript, WinJS type apps.

I normally use localStorage to store most information, and I know how to navigate to where that localStorage is in the file system:

`C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\-package-string-` is the base folder for all the info, and I drill down to `\AC\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\DOMStore` and the localStorage xml file is in there in one of the

Knowing this makes it easy for me to take localStorage from one persons app, download it and put it into my debugging app and investigate any problems they might have related to their localStorage.

I need the same info for IndexedDb. I use Dexie.js which uses IndexedDb and I want to be able to move the file from one persons computer onto my own to debug it if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10 (v1803) is IndexedDB located in:

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\--package-string--\AppData\Indexed DB
```